# Using RequireJS to get information from a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, flask, requirejs

I'm trying to use requireJS to open a JSON after an area is clicked, and then search in it for a object that has the "Country" = to the title of the clicked area, but as of right now all I'm getting is a "script error with './olympics.json'" error message.

olympics.json:

```
{
"list": [
{
"Country": "United States",
"IOC": "USA",
"Summer_Gold": "1,070",
"Summer_Silver": 841,
"Summer_Bronze": 745,
"Summer_Total": "2,656",
"Winter_Gold": 105,
"Winter_Silver": 113,
"Winter_Bronze": 89,
"Winter_Total": 307,
"Total_Gold": "1,175",
"Total_Silver": 954,
"Total_Bronze": 834,
"Total_Total": "2,963"
},
...
]}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="europe_img" src="https://mapswire.com/download/europe/europe-political-map-miller.jpg" usemap="#europe" alt="Europe">
<map name="europe">
    <area class="ModArea" target="" alt="Iceland" title="Iceland" coords="138,388,35,540,232,748,549,585,516,374"
          shape="poly" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
          
    <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="country_name"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p id="IOC">IOC: </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</map>
```

JS:

```
$(".ModArea").click(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('title');
        $("#country_name").html(name);
        require(['../olympics.json'], function (json) {
            $("#IOC").html(json.list.find(element => element.Country === name));
        });
    });
```

[Error message from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMYiR.png)

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkzMZ.png)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the error's console stacktrace.

Comment: @NiceBooks added it, checking now it seems it's trying to open "olympics.json.js", a file that doesn't exist. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: You need to use the correct path for olympics.json
Suppose you are launching the server from the app & the file is in app/f1/f2/olympics.json folder, the path should be /f1/f2/olympics.json

Comment: The html file in where the js script is located is inside the folder "templates", while the json file is outside of it, so isn't "../olympics.json" correct? Because from what I know using .. means that the file is outside of the current folder

Comment: .. means the parent of the current folder. Please post your folder structure if possible.

Comment: added it to the original post, the script is in europe.html right now

Comment: Try /olympics.json 
Since this is a Flask project, tryp putting olympics.json in the static folder if necessary.
It's better to add a flask tag to this question to get help from flask experienced devs.

Comment: @NiceBooks moving it to static made it finally load, but now I'm getting 2 new errors: the ":" after "list" in the second row is being reffered as "unexpected token", and the "json" in the $("#IOC")... section is undefined

Comment: Check using https://jsonlint.com/ to check for json errors, if it still doesn't work, please post a new question (JavaScript)

Comment: @NiceBooks it says it's a valid JSON, so I'll post a new question

Comment: I do believe that you have to use the RequireJS JSON plugin: https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins